# Get last modified date of a remote file

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have an app with which at startup it downloads a file from a remote location (through the net) and parses it's contents.

I am trying to speed up the process of startup as the bigger the file gets the slower the app starts.

As a way to speed up the process I thought of getting the last modified date of the file and if it is newer from the file on the user's pc then and only then download it. 
I have found many ways to do it online but none of them are in C# (for windows store apps). Does anybody here know of a way of doing this without the need to download the file? If I am to download the file then the process is sped up at all.

My C# code for downloading the file currently is this

```
const string fileLocation = "link to dropbox";
            var uri = new Uri(fileLocation);
            var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("feedlist.txt",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(uri, file); 
            await download.StartAsync();
```

If it helps the file is stored in dropbox but if any of you guys have a suggestion for another free file hosting service I am open to suggestions

Comment: You could instead have the server (remote location) create somewhat of an index file of the following structure: filename, last-modified data (I'd advise you to use a checksum instead), have the client download this string, compare the date (or the checksum ^^), if different, delete and download.

Comment: Well to be honest the remote location is a public folder in dropbox :D cheaper for now :D

Comment: What are the protocols you can use? I'm sorry, I never used DropBox. With SFTP you can get that kind of info, I think.

Comment: To be honest I have no Idea. I will search and let you know. I am downloading using http currently. I'll add my download code if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can check the file time by [sending HEAD request](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/14b3ee11-0492-4111-b6c5-217b5fcf0a2e/sending-a-http-head-request-in-c) and parsing/looking HTTP header response for a `Last-Modified` filed. The remote server should support it and DropBox does not support this feature for direct links (only via API). But DropBox have another feature, the headers have the `etag` field. You should store it and check in the next request. If it changed - the file has been changed too. You can use [this tool](http://web-sniffer.net/) to check the remote file headers.

Comment: It's just a tool that have hundreds realizations in the web. Solution in the text.